# Redirect Desktop Traffic using html

Tags: html, redirect, desktop, traffic

We're trying to redirect our desktop traffic.

Example:

We have this subdomain:

```
xxxx.domain.com/test
```

This domains is used for mobile traffic, so, when the traffic is from desktop we want redirect to:

```
domain.com/test
```

Basically we have a lot of landing pages for mobile and for desktop, but I need chose what desktop landing need redirect the traffic for each HTML page.

How we can do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections

Answer (score 0):

Check mobile (javascript):

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 window.location.href = 'xxxx.domain.com/test';
}else{
window.location.href = 'domain.com/test';
}
```

Check mobile (PHP):

```
$android = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),"android");
$ipad = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),"ipad");
$iphone = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),"iphone");
$ipod = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),"ipod");

if (($android === false) && ($ipad === false) && ($iphone === false) && ($ipod === false))
  $mobile = "false";
else 
   $mobile = "true";
```

Comment: But what is the code in order to integrate in our html page to drive the desktop traffic to domain.com/test? And keep mobile landing if the user use a mobile.

Comment: Thanks d.mares. Just a question. How can i integrate this code in .html website? So, this code i think working in .php right?